# Is it possible to show some limited menu list on primary menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a primary menu and code is

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation float-right">
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1','menu_id'=> 'primary-menu') );?>
 </nav>
```

Now I am using the same menu for my left sidebar

```
<nav id="left-side-menu" class="main-navigation">
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1', 'menu_id' => 'left-primary-menu',) );?>        
 </nav>
```

I have the total number of 15 menu list but I have to show 8 on my `primary-menu` and all the menu list will display on `left-primary-menu`.

So is it possible to show some limited menu list on the primary menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try This Functions

```
//Used This Function for Register Menus
function twentytwenty_menus() {
    $locations = array(
        'primary'  => __( 'Desktop Horizontal Menu', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'leftsidebar'   => __( 'Slidebar Menu', 'twentytwenty' ),   
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );
}
add_action( 'init', 'twentytwenty_menus' );


//Used This Function for set Limit of Menu Items
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'mytheme_menufilter', 10, 2 );
function mytheme_menufilter($items, $args) {
    // want our MAINMENU to have MAX of 7 items
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        $toplinks = 0;
        foreach ( $items as $k => $v ) {
            if ( $v->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {
                // count how many top-level links we have so far...
                $toplinks++;
            }
            // if we've passed our max # ...
            if ( $toplinks > 2 ) {
                unset($items[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: Step One:
Create Menu locations for header and  Sidebar bar using 'register_nav_menus' function

Step Two:
First Create menu and used for both 'primary' and 'leftsidebar' locations then used 'mytheme_menufilter' function for set Limit of Menu Items

Comment: I have created only one menu and calling the same menu twice with a different id. I think register_nav_menus is already in the wordpress.

Comment: Using 'register_nav_menus' function you can create different menu locations then assign same menu for different locations.

Comment: ok. Also where you set the limit of the menu.  I mean I have to displaying 8 menu list on primary menu.

Comment: Set Menu location at 'if ( $args->theme_location == 'MENU LOCATION' )' condition and Set Menu Limits at ' if ( $toplinks > 2 )' condition

Comment: I have to change it only this $toplinks > 2 condition right?

Comment: Yes You Can change it only this "$toplinks > 2" condition for Set Menu Limit and also Change Menu Location at "$args->theme_location == 'MENU LOCATION'" condition for Different  Menu Locations

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly for me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your work you can use the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
function modify_wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
        if( $args->theme_location == 'menu-1' && $args->menu_id == 'left-primary-menu' ) { // if valid your conditions
            // do your modification with $items here
            $items = array_slice( $items, 0, 8 ); // first 8 items
        }
        return $items;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'modify_wp_nav_menu_objects', 99, 2 );
```